# Bigcommerce-Transitioning from Blueprint to Stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

I am going to translate my bigcommerce store from buleprint to stencil. Because My site is live now, I am afraid if there will be something wrong when I translate it to stencil theme. So I want to know if I need to backup something firstly or if there are something I need to notice.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

When you switch from a Blueprint theme to a Stencil theme, you will have an option to download your theme customization.

[image]